# Location of web app on my server and Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm having a rough time with Apache and my Rails app on my production server. I have everything installed, libraries, gems, the whole get down. The issue is that I get a "Forbidden" error in my browser. I've even chmod'd my app directory with "777" but still no luck.

So my questions are:

1. What is your `ServerName` Directive (in your virtual host configuration)?
2. Where is your application located on your server?
3. Who owns your application directory?
4. What user *should* own your application directory?

Comment: `chmod 777` is probably not the right answer. You need to make sure the `Allow` and `Deny` directives are applied correctly to the location. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

Comment: I am pretty sure that there are plenty of simple and short howtos on the net that explain how to get a simple rails app running. Have you searched for them?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, and yes, I've searched for a solution, and I've setup several servers in the past, that is why this is soo baffling to me. It seems like I have every correct and wanted to see how everyone else has there server configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Apache has the Passenger (aka mod_rails) module installed and enabled, configuring a new Rails app is as simple as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  # DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /path/to/app/public

  # Custom log file locations
  ErrorLog  /path/to/log/example.com/error.log
  CustomLog /path/to/log/example.com/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Some important notes:

1. the default environment is "production"
2. be sure your DocumentRoot points to the /public folder of your app, not to the app root